# Copy S3 user metadata with file

Tags: amazon-s3, metadata

I copy files from one bucket to another. The files have [user metadata](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingMetadata.html#UserMetadata) attached.

> How can I copy the metadata together with the files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dragondisk does this:
http://www.s3-client.com/
Open one bucket on one side, then another bucket on the other and copy and paste between them to move the files and meta data.

The amazon cli also does it - see this SO answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43219427/1216286

Currently (October 2017) the amazon web client **does not** copy it.