# File metadata not kept in S3 after a CLI copy

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have two buckets (let‘s say A and B) in different regions. I have archives in the bucket A with a metadata (x-amz-meta-mymeta). I do perform a copy command using the CLI:

```
aws s3 cp s3://A/${file}.tar.gz s3://B/
```

Depending on the file, metadata are kept or not. Files `pikachu` have both the same metadata after the copy, but a file `pika-chu` does not have the metadata in the target bucket B.

I have read the doc but could not find any other information than the one exposed in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43219427/1222135).

The metadata is lost even though the destination file already exists or not.

Any hints on that?

**Edit**: metadata is lost even if the copy command is

```
aws s3 cp s3://A/${file}.tar.gz s3://B/${file}
```

**Edit**: For info, the size of the files differs, `pikachu` is few Mb large whereas `pika-chu` is more like 50Mb.

**Edit**: Files are uploaded using `aws s3 cp` with no multipart information.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is the official documentation on the PUT COPY REST API.

Look into the x-amz-metadata-directive.

[REST Object Copy](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTObjectCOPY.html)

For the CLI add (valid only for files smaller than 5 GB and no multipart copy / upload - multipart copy does not preserve all headers):

```
--metadata-directive COPY
```

> --metadata-directive (string) Specifies whether the metadata is copied from the source object or replaced with metadata provided when copying
>   S3 objects. Note that if the object is copied over in parts, the
>   source object's metadata will not be copied over, no matter the value
>   for --metadata-directive, and instead the desired metadata values must
>   be specified as parameters on the command line. Valid values are COPY
>   and REPLACE. If this parameter is not specified, COPY will be used by
>   default. If REPLACE is used, the copied object will only have the
>   metadata values that were specified by the CLI command. Note that if
>   you are using any of the following parameters: --content-type,
>   content-language, --content-encoding, --content-disposition,
>   --cache-control, or --expires, you will need to specify --metadata-directive REPLACE for non-multipart copies if you want the copied objects to have the specified metadata values.

[EDIT after question]

The AWS CLI will automatically use multipart upload. This is configurable. This link shows the S3 configuration options.

[AWS CLI S3 Configuration](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/topic/s3-config.html)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. It does not work even with the `--metadata-directive`. As far as I can understand, the first file is uploaded as-is whereas the second file is uploaded in multipart. That makes sense. I have added the size of the files in the question.

Comment: I never explicitely told S3 to use multipart. Is it using it depending on the size of the file ?

Comment: @greg. I update my answer with S3 configuration options. In the link provided the default is 64 MB. multipart_threshold = 64MB

Comment: the setting default is 8MB ! This explains why the files bigger than that lose their metadata. Bingo, I will try to change that setting on Monday to check if that’s the cause.

Comment: I ran into this seemingly odd behavior as well and the only way I could see to make it more predictable is by using the --content-type flag. Interestingly enough if you upload via the console it always works as expected, it's from the CLI that it doesn't handle the gzip files well

Answer (score 0):

Files bigger than 5 GB lose their metadata when copied, see https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java/issues/367